# Derivation of non-local conserved charges

Tags: quantum-field-theory, noethers-theorem, integrable-systems

Consider a 2D sigma model with a symmetry group $G$ and whose generators obey $$[T_A, T_B] = f^C_{AB} T_C$$ and whose conserved currents are Lie algebra-valued, i.e. $$j_{\mu} = j_{\mu}^A T_A$$ and $$\partial_{\mu} j^{\mu A} = 0.$$

From this it is straightforward to construct a conserved quantity $$Q^A = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} j^{0A} (x,t) dx$$ where $$\dot{Q}^A = 0.$$

In integrable systems, we can generate an infinite amount of additional, non-local conserved charges if the current satisfies the flatness condition
$$
\partial_{\mu} j_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu} j_{\mu} + [j_{\mu}, j_{\nu} ] = 0 ~,
$$
where indices are raised/lowered with a Lorentzian metric. The first of these non-local charges is given as

$$
Q^{A~(1)} = f^A_{BC} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \int_x^{\infty} dy \; j^{0B}(x,t) j^{0C}(y,t) - 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \; j_1^A(x,t) ~.
$$

I don't understand how this result is obtained from the flatness condition, and I can't find a derivation anywhere (the result is just stated, e.g. in section 2 of http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0308089 and equations (11-12) of http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0404003).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the celebrated nonlocal Yangian construction.  It is reviewed in, e.g. [Curtright & Zachos 1992](https://www.academia.edu/10283991/Supersymmetry_and_the_nonlocal_yangian_deformation_symmetry), [i.e.](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9210060). I assume you can easily check conservation of the charge you wrote down?

Comment: @CosmasZachos  I have copied them, and deleted my answer, will try to make a simple answer, so you may delete these since they are irrelevant to the question, thanks

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92316/lax-pair-for-principal-chiral-model?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

Your sources are particularly unhelpful, bibliographically speaking. The original recursive construction of these nonlocal currents is, of course, 
E Brézin, C Itzykson, J Zinn-Justin, J-B Zuber, Phys Lett **B** 82 (1979)  442-444, (https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(79)90263-6 ) .
But, by now, the Yangian structure of them  has been streamlined much better -- see below.

To start with, reassure yourself that, indeed, $\dot{Q}^{(1)}$ vanishes, 
since it is the charge of the first non-local current,
$$
j^{(1)}_\mu(x)=\tilde {j}_\mu(x) +\tfrac{1}{2}[~j_\mu (x), \int_{-\infty}^{x} \!\!dy ~~  j_0(y)],
$$
where I have reverted to Lie-Algebra-valued currents *j<sub>μ</sub>*, as in your flatness condition,
$$
(\partial_\mu + j_{\mu} ) ~\tilde{j}_\mu =0~.
$$
By virtue of this flatness condition and conservation, in 2 dimensions, you then see that 
$$
\partial^\mu \int_{-\infty}^{x} dy ~~j_0(y) =\tilde{j}^\mu .
$$

It is then straightforward to see, given the conservation of $j_\mu$, that
$$
\partial^\mu j_\mu^{(1)}= \partial\cdot \tilde{j}+ \tfrac{1}{2}[j_\mu (x), \partial^\mu\int_{-\infty}^{x} dy ~~j_0(y)]= \tfrac{1}{2}[~j_\mu (x),\tilde{j}^\mu  ] -   \tfrac{1}{2}[j_\mu (x),    \tilde{j}_\mu] =0~, $$
leading to the time invariance of the corresponding charge.

It is much more efficient to think of all these nonlocal currents as just ***one*** conserved master current which, however, depends on an arbitrary spectral parameter *θ*; so a generating function. The coefficients of each power of *θ* will then be separately conserved, and the 0th order will be the starting local current, the term linear in *θ* the above nonlocal current, and so on ad infinitum, for increasingly nonlocal currents. See T Curtright & C Zachos, Nucl Phys **B** 402 (1993) 604-612 (https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(93)90120-E) .

First define (with Polyakov),
$$
C_\mu (x,\theta)= \tfrac{1}{2}   (1-\cosh \theta)~ j_\mu  -\tfrac{1}{2}\sinh\theta ~\tilde{j}_\mu  \\
K_\mu  (x,\theta)=\cosh \theta ~j_\mu+\sinh \theta ~\tilde{j}_\mu    \\
\chi (x,\theta)= \operatorname {P} e^{-\int_{-\infty}^x dy C_1 (y,\theta)},
$$
the last a path ordered exponential. These are seen to satisfy 
$$
(\partial^\mu+C^{\mu}) \tilde {C} _\mu= 0\\
  \partial^\mu K_\mu +[C^\mu , K_\mu ]=0\\
\partial_\mu \chi=-C_\mu \chi .
$$

Given these, you may prove conservation of the master Yangian current,
$$
{\cal J}_\mu(x,\theta)=\chi^{-1} K_\mu ~\chi= j_\mu+\theta ~j^{(1)}_\mu+…
$$
So the above conservation proof of the first nonlocal current is but the warmup for the conservation proof of *all nonlocal currents*.